# Application.LoadLevel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my game switch levels through a collision with an object tagged as `Complete`.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int currentLevel = 0;

    void OncollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Complete") {
            Application.LoadLevel (currentLevel + 1);
            currentLevel + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error, but it simply does not work. Could anyone help me resolve my problem? I do in fact have the levels in the build settings.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. What is it doing or not doing, exactly?

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/302653

Comment: OncollisionEnter is case sensitive use OnCollisionEnter

Comment: `currentLevel + 1;` perhaps you want to do `currentLevel = currentLevel + 1;`? Now the value is not stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. If it doesnt work show more code (on the other object);

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int currentLevel = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Complete") {
            currentLevel++; //first change level number
            Application.LoadLevel (currentLevel); //then load
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, can we maybe talk somewhere I have alot of beginner questions

Comment: @Matt sure, you can send me private message

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead, as transforms don't exactly have a tag, but it is the gameObject itself that has the tag. Also using .CompareTag() is more efficient than comparing with the equals operator.

```
if(other.CompareTag("Complete")){
your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce, I like using this now!

Answer (score 0):

When you load another level, you load another scene with another script and gameObjects in scene. So you are in scene `0` and try to load scene `1`, After you load scene `1`, you are in new scene. I assuming you have this script in level `1` too, But `currentLevel` variable will be zero because it is a new script.

So you have some options, First **try to keep this script alive between scene load** (Which I not recommending) **or save the value** of `currentLevel` **and read that value** in other scene. You can learn more about both of this from here: [PERSISTENCE - SAVING AND LOADING DATA](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/persistence-data-saving-loading)

Comment: I will in fact look into it!

Answer (score 0):

So lets list some possible mistakes in your script:

1: OncollisionEnter should be OnCollisionEnter;

2: This behaviour needs to be attached on your game object that will collide with the object tagged "Complete" (I mean, if this is attached to some object GameManager in your scene and you want that when your Player that is another GameObject in same scene and is not parent of GameManager, this will not work. You'll need OnCollisionEnter to be as behaviour of your GameObject involved in collision with the one tagged "Complete" ).

3: Even if it work to go into level 1 first time it will continuous reset to level 1 when you're at level 1 as changing between scenes will destroyed and reconstruct every GameObject if you doesn't implicit tell Unity do don't do it calling DontDestoyOnLoad() at Awake() or Start() methods of your GameManager.

4: Even if you put it in both scenes, if you don't adjust currentLevel in inspector for each scene when you change scene it will take always 0 and will try to load always scene 1;

5: Your Application.LoadLevel() should be at LateUpdate or some state that will ensure that every concurrent processing in your frame will be completed before you try to load a new scene. Unity can handle this almost perfect but you can avoid some problems using this wisely. So, set a boolean or something indicating that you collided and want to load another scene and call for real LoadLevel at the final of your main loot process...